# inequivalent norms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

I am thinking about the following question:

Let $X$ be a Banach space, say separable, e.g., $l_p$ or $c_0$. 
When can I say that there exist inequivalent complete norms on $X$?

Comment: Just to clarify what the question is: We are given some *vector space* $X$ and the question is whether there are two norms which make $X$ into a Banach space (i.e., a complete normed space) and these two norms are not equivalent?

Comment: if the space is finite, then I think all norms are equivalent

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Yes. I am particularly interested in the case of $l_p$

Comment: By "*a complete norm on $X$*" you mean a norm $\|\cdot\|'$ that is continuous on $(X,\cdot)$ (where $\|\cdot\|$ is the original norm) and such that $(X,\|\cdot\|')$ is complete?

Comment: @YCor dosent a banach space inply the space is complete with respect to the norm

Comment: @YCor  Actually, I just meant that both $(X, \|\cdot\|')$ and $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ are Banach spaces

Comment: So you're not assuming that $\|\cdot\|'$ is continuous? Then it's quite easy to produce plenty of inequivalent norms.

Comment: @YCor Yes. I think if it is continuous, then by open mapping theorem, they have to be equivalent. So, please, show me, for example, are there any inequivalent norms for $l_p$?

Comment: Abstractly the $l_p$ ($p \neq \infty$) and $c_0$ both $\mathbb C$-vector spaces with basis of size $2^{\aleph_0}$, so there is some linear (not bounded) isomorphism $A : l_p \to c_0$ of $\mathbb C$-vector spaces, for $x \in l_p$ define $||x||_{c_0} := ||Ax||_{c_0}$, then $(l_p, || \cdot ||_{c_0})$ isomorphic to $(c_0, || \cdot ||_{c_0})$ as Banach space . In fact, you can do the same trick with any two infinitely-dimensional separable Banach spaces.

Comment: If $X$ is a separable Banach space then it has cardinal $c$, and so does its automorphism group (group of bicontinuous linear automorphisms). But its automorphism group as vector space has cardinal $2^c$. So you get $2^c$ pairwise non-equivalent norms. I think the question is better suited for MathSE.

Comment: @kp9r4d I am sorry. I can not really see the connection between your answer and my question

Comment: @YCor Well. Could you supply a concrete example?

Comment: @YCor  Alright. Anyway, thank you very much for helping

Comment: No, this proof doesn't provide any concrete example. It might be true that "every norm on $\ell^2$ is continuous" is consistent with ZF+DC.

Comment: @YCor Indeed, your statement is exactly what I am looking for, and I can not find any references for it.

Comment: Answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2339334/17929

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me mention the result of Mackey: *if $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, then its Hamel dimension* (= dimension as abstract vector space, over $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$) *is $\ge c=2^{\aleph_0}$, with equality if $X$ is separable*.

In the separable case, $X$ has cardinal $\le c$ so the upper bound is clear. The lower bound is trivial under CH (continuum hypothesis) using Baire. In general (i.e., not assuming CH), here's a proof of $\ge$ due to Lacey (mentioned at MathSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141543/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1899365/35400)). Using Hahn-Banach, there exist sequences $(x_n)$ and $(\ell_n)$ in $X$ and $X^*$ (the topological dual) such that $\ell_m(x_n)=\delta_{m,n}$ for all $m,n$ (Kronecker's $\delta$). It follows that for every $n$, $x_n\notin\overline{\mathrm{span}\{x_m:m\neq n\}}$. Now use the existence of a family $(J_t)_t$ of cardinal $c$ of infinite subsets of $\mathbf{N}$ with pairwise finite intersection. [To obtain this, take the countable set as the set of vertices of an infinite regular rooted binary tree, and the subsets as the set of infinite geodesic rays starting from the root.] Then the family $(y_t)$ defined by $y_t=\sum_{n\in J_t}2^{-n}x_n$ is linearly independent by an easy argument.

(Of course in $\ell^p$ or $c_0$ one can produce these elements without using Hahn-Banach, namely $x_n$ can be chosen as Dirac at $n$.)

---

Next, the assertion is that *for a vector space $V$ of infinite dimension $\alpha$ over a field $K$ of cardinal $\beta$ with $\beta\le 2^\alpha$, the cardinal of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is $\beta^\alpha$, and in particular equals $2^\alpha$ if $\beta\le 2^\alpha$ (which is automatic if the field has cardinal $\beta\le c$).*

For the latter fact, just use that $\beta^\alpha\le (2^\alpha)^\alpha=2^{\alpha\times\alpha}=2^\alpha$.

For the upper bound, do it for $\mathrm{End}(V)$, which is in bijection with the set of maps $\alpha\to V$, i.e., has cardinal $\beta^\alpha$.

For the lower bound, splitting a basis, write $V=W\oplus W$ with $W$ isomorphic to $V$. Then every $u\in\mathrm{End}(W)$ induces $f_u:(x,y)\mapsto (x+u(y),y)$, with $f\in\mathrm{GL}(V)$, these provide $\beta^\alpha$ automorphisms. (Alternatively we already get $2^\alpha$ automorphisms by permuting basis elements— say gather elements by pairs and for any subset of this set of $\alpha$ pairs transpose them and leave identity elsewhere.)

---

Combining, we obtain that for $X$ infinite-dimensional separable Banach space, the automorphism group $G_X$ of $X$ as abstract vector space (over $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$) has cardinal $2^c$.

If $H_X\subset G_X$ is the subgroup of (bi)continuous automorphisms then $H_X$ has cardinal $\le c$ and hence $G_X/H_X$ has cardinal $2^c$, so the $g\cdot (\|\cdot\|)$, when $g$ ranges over $G_X/H_X$, yield $2^c$ pairwise non-equivalent norms on $X$.

One can elaborate using cardinal invariants about the non-separable case, but for free we get $2^c$ non-equivalent norms in $X$ without assumption: choose an infinite-dimensional separable subspace $Y$, and define $G$ as the group of abstract linear automorphisms of $X$ that preserve $Y$, and $H$ its subgroup of bicontinuous automorphisms: then looking at the action on $Y$ shows that $H$ has index $\ge 2^c$ in $G$, and again the $g\cdot (\|\cdot\|)$ for $g$ ranging over $G/H$ are pairwise non-equivalent norms on $X$ (they're non-equivalent since they're non-equivalent in restriction to $Y$).

Comment: Note: proving that there's a non-equivalent norm is easier than all this (no need to use the $2^{\aleph_0}$ fact). Namely, if $X$ is an infinite-dim normed space, find a basis $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ contained in the 1-sphere. For every family $(t_i)$ of nonzero scalars, $v_i\mapsto t_iv_i$ defines a linear automorphism. Choosing $(t_i)$ unbounded yields a non-continuous automorphism. Choosing different families easily yields a group of $c$ such automorphisms, each unbounded except identity, and hence this yields $c$ pairwise non-equivalent norms (but $2^c$ is hopeless if the dimension is countable).

Answer (score 3):

Am I confused? The Hamel dimension of any infinite dimensional separable Banach space is $2^{\aleph_0}$, so they are all the same as vector spaces. So the underlying vector space of one of them can be the underlying vector space of *any* of them.

Comment: Actually, I see that kp9r4d already said this in the comments.

Comment: I actually provided a reference and a proof in my answer.

Comment: @YCor you're right, I should have read your answer before writing mine.